# C# How to disable the useage of pointers (How to clone a non-cloneable variable)

Tags: c#, pointers, clone

**The Problem**

Hello stackoverflow. I have ran into a problem.
Even though C# automatically enables the usage of pointers, which is VERY helpful, I need to clone a non-cloneable variable for a second (an int).

**My Code**

I have a

```
public int FirstLine 
{ 
    get { return Convert.ToInt32(File.ReadAllLines(@"example.txt")[0]); } 
    set { File.WriteAllLines(@"example.txt", new string[1]{ value.ToString() }); } 
}
```

that I'm using to have a variable that's grabbed from a file when accessed to read, and if being accessed to write, it writes the value to the file, to have a variable that updates on demand and saves.

I know that the example code is very "unsafe" to speak, I'm just throwing together a rough example of what I'm doing. Somewhere else in my code, I access this variable:

`int GettingVariable = FirstLine;`

and since C# automatically uses pointers, `GettingVariable` will automatically be updated on file demand, which is NOT what I want.

**What I'd like as an answer**

I'd like to be able to clone the int, to disable the pointers use, as well as not having to use an `unsafe void` (if possible). Since there is no built in int.Clone(), How could I manage this?

Answer (score 3):

> since C# automatically uses pointers, `GettingVariable` will automatically be updated on file demand, which is NOT what I want.

This is not true.  That code is not using any pointers, and the value in question *is* copied, and will not observe any changes to that file or the object that is accessing it.

> I'd like to be able to clone the int, to disable the pointers use, as well as not having to use an `unsafe void` (if possible). Since there is no built in int.Clone(), How could I manage this?

Use the code you already have.  It already has the semantics you're asking for.

Comment: Sorry, my Visual Studio was (and still is) acting super weird and not building. Since it's acting weird, it built an older version, and since the code I put wasn't working, it triggered this kind of logic to go on in my brain, and ask a question. I'm terribly sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 0):

Servy is absolutely correct.

To give you a little more background, C# is *not* "using pointers" as you've described - `class` objects act *like* double pointers (ie `**MyClass myVariable`), particularly when dealing with `ref` and `out` methods, while `struct` objects exhibit the semantics described above.

Rather than thinking of all C# as a wrapper around C++, you should familiarize yourself with C# semantics, particularly when you get to the point you've clearly reached. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> and since C# automatically uses pointers, GettingVariable will
>   automatically be updated on file demand, which is NOT what I want.

This is where I think you are going wrong. It's because you are using Properties rather than a variable and I assume accessing the property each time, nothing to do with pointers. So for example with this code :

```
public int FirstLine 
{ 
    get { return Convert.ToInt32(File.ReadAllLines(@"example.txt")[0]);
}
```

Each time you try and get the value of Firstline it is going to run that code. But if you already have the value, it won't change. For example  :

```
object.FirstLine = 5;
int firstlineA = object.FirstLine; //Returns 5
object.FirstLine = 10;
int firstLineB = object.FirstLine; //Returns 10
int firstlineC = firstlineA; //Still returns 5
```